# @ViewById does not work

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-annotations, findviewbyid

Here is my code

**Activity:**

```
@RoboGuice
@EActivity(R.layout.result_page)
public class ResultActivity extends SherlockListActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener{
    @ViewById TextView src;
    @ViewById TextView dest;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(src==null || dest==null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "@ViewById does not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //More Code here

    }
}
```

**Part of layout: - Note: There are many nested layouts - showing only a part of the layout file**

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/topRight"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/topLeft"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8">
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/src"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#3399FF"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:textSize="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottomRight"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bottomLeft"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8">
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dest"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="#3399FF"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:textSize="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to do a **setText()** on the TextViews. I wonder if my implementing the Interface(which I need) makes the @ViewById to malfuntiion. Or am I missing out something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spikas reply is not correct, you dont have to use findViewById when you use @ViewById in android annotations. The thing is that the views have not been injected yet in the onCreate. Try accessing them in a method annotated with @AfterViews, which is guaranteed to be executed after the views have been injected.

for example:

```
@AfterViews
void checkViews(){
if(src!=null && dest!=null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "@ViewById does work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```